# Parent process stops waiting after receiving and trapping signal from child?

Tags: shell, sh

I have written a script in shell and encountered a behavior that I do not fully understand. Namely this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# traps SIGINT and only echoes
trap 'trapINT' INT
trapINT() {
  echo "Child calling."
}

# sleeps for i seconds, then prints i and
# sends a SIGINT to parent
sleep_and_echo() {
  sleep $1
  echo $1
  kill -INT $2
} 

# Main loop, spawn three children
for i in $(seq 1 3); do
  sleep_and_echo $i $$ &
  echo "Process no. $i with PID $! executed."
done

# wait for all the children to finish?
wait

echo "Waiting done."
exit
```

At first I thought that for each child the parent will receive a SIGINT, will trap it not interrupt and then will wait for the children to end, then will echo that his children ended and will end himself.

However, the process does a stange thing and seems to abandon his waiting after receiving the first SIGINT from his first children (i = 1). Here's a  terminal exectuion of the script:

```
ashen@SummerParadise:~/School/UNIX/8-DU$ ./examp.sh
Process no. 1 with PID 3904 executed.
Process no. 2 with PID 3905 executed.
Process no. 3 with PID 3906 executed.
1
child calling
Waiting done.
ashen@SummerParadise:~/School/UNIX/8-DU$ 2
./examp.sh: 11: kill: No such process

3
./examp.sh: 11: kill: No such process

^C
```

Can anybody explain this behavior? I wanted to do a script that waits for his children and only allows up to $1 to be running at the same time, recieving a signal if one ends and launching another one but the fact that he stops waiting after the trap routine ruined this thought.

Thank you

Comment: I believe the `wait` is getting the signal first and dying and then passing the signal up to your script (which catches it and continues from the, now dead, `wait`). You need to re-`wait` in the handler I think. Also `INT` might not be the best signal to use here. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap for some details.

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem! :) Also the explanation makes sense now that you pointed it out about wait getting the signal first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you just `wait` in the handler or something else?

Comment: There's no need for the children signal the parent. The parent receives SIGCHLD when the child exits (that's how `wait` *works*)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a nice description in the posix docs, but the bash manpage says:

When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command
       via the wait builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin
       to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

So you can retry the wait by doing:

```
(exit 129)
while $? -gt 128; do wait; done
```